# Trying to get a "variable" from a struct but when I try it says struct has no member "variable"

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have a Codable struct

```
struct FareComponentList: Codable {
    let passengerFareInfoList: [PassengerFareInfoList]
    let pricingOverview: PricingOverview
}
```

I want to access pricingOverview element.

I tried several ways

```
1)
root.availabilityResultList.first?.availabilityRouteList.first?.availabilityByDateList.first?.originDestinationOptionList.first?.fareComponentGroupList?.first?. pricingOverview
2)
root.availabilityResultList.first?.availabilityRouteList.first?.availabilityByDateList.first?.originDestinationOptionList.first?.fareComponentGroupList?.[0]. pricingOverview
```

but it always returns nil

then I tried

```
let x = root.availabilityResultList.first?.availabilityRouteList.first?.availabilityByDateList.first?.originDestinationOptionList.first?.fareComponentGroupList
```

```
taxprice.append(x?.fareComponentList)
```

Gives this error , Value of type '[FareComponentGroupList]' has no member 'fareComponentList'

How can I fix this error / how can I get the value from pricingOverview?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Same as Zyfe3r?

Comment: Same school same thing to do. And we are stuck !

Comment: Then work it out together.

Comment: Once again, please learn the stuff. `[...]` represents an array, a list/sequence of items. A struct member is only available for a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your struct as "`FareComponentList`" which has "`PricingOverview`". But you are trying to access "`PricingOverview`" from different name "`FareComponentGroupList`".